# Laravel: Event listener wildcard not firing

Tags: php, laravel-4, listener

I have an event listener that uses a wild card to listen for any `sentinel.user.*` event.

Here's the listener:

```
Event::listen('sentinel.user.*', function ($userID = null){
    error_log('log listener fired');
    $userLog           = new UserLog;
    $EventNameExploded = explode("." , Event::firing());
    $EventNameEnding   = array_pop($EventNameExploded);
    $logAction         = "User " . $EventNameEnding;
    $logData           = array('eventDescription' => $logAction);

    $userLog->submitLog($logData,$userID);
},99);
```

For some reason this doesn't fire for the `sentinel.user.forgot` event. It does fire for any other `sentinel.user` event.

While troubleshooting, I added a listener for the specific `sentinel.user.forgot` event:

```
Event::listen('sentinel.user.forgot', function (){
    error_log('forgot listener fired');
}, 98);
```

This event listener will fire. I even gave it a priority that was lower than the log event and the log event will not fire but the forgot specific one will fire. I have no even listeners with a priority higher than `99` or `98`.

Does anyone know why the listener isn't firing???

EDIT:

Here's the code that fires the `sentinel.user.forgot` event:

```
public function forgot()
{
    // Form Processing
    $result = $this->forgotPasswordForm->forgot( Input::all() );

    if( $result['success'] )
    {
        Event::fire('sentinel.user.forgot', array(
            'email'     => $result['mailData']['email'],
            'userId'    => $result['mailData']['userId'],
            'resetCode' => $result['mailData']['resetCode']
        ));

        // Success!
        Session::flash('success', $result['message']);
        return Redirect::route('home');
    } 
    else 
    {
        Session::flash('error', $result['message']);
        return Redirect::route('Sentinel\forgotPasswordForm')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors( $this->forgotPasswordForm->errors() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that sends the `forgot` event ?

Comment: Sure. I'll update my main message.